# Can I run java code in html textbox?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am writing one web page in which I am putting one html input type="textarea" in which user will write their java code and on submit it will return output of that java code. Can I do this using jsp? if not then what are the other ways.

Comment: Yes you can do this, but you will most likely need a server roundtrip.

Answer (score 5):

I would think very carefully before allowing people to do that.

At the very least, to read and run the user's input, you will need a JDK to compile it, and a JVM to run it.  Since you're talking about over the web, presumably the user's machine will not have those (otherwise they'd just use theirs), so you'd have to use the ones on your server - that is, take the user's text, upload it as a .java file to your server, compile and run it (for an anonymous user on your server!), and send the result back to the browser session.

As you can see, there are a couple of pretty big, bad security problems here.  Not recommended !